# Soy principiante en C# y desde hace poco cuando abro mi proyecto el programa no detecta: puntos y comas comillas etc

Tags: c#

Esto es fácil de explicar, pero no se como solucionarlo, lo que pasa es que cuando abro mi programa los comentarios que se hacen con las // los detecta como palabras puestas sin sentido, eso con todas las comas, comillas, puntos, puntos y comas.
He probado a abrir un nuevo programa, hacer lo mismo y cuando lo abro al día siguiente me pasa lo mismo, voy ha dejar unas fotos para que veáis como es el error y así podréis valorarlo vosotros. Si necesitáis mas información que no salga en la foto por favor preguntar me lo y os diré lo que sepa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con la tecla "Impr Pant" (o "Prt Sc" en inglés) se copia en el portapapeles la pantalla y puedes pegarla en un programa de edición gráfica (por ejemplo MS Paint), para tener una imagen mucho mejor. Además, si antes de hacerlo pasas el ratón por el primer error, saldrá un "caption" informándote del mensaje de error que también es importante.

Comment: Deberías mostrar ademas la lista de errores por si vieramos algo relevante. El error es extraño de todas maneras, tal vez una resinstalacion de visual studio lo solucionara...

Comment: Lo impotante seria revisar el "Error List" para ver que menciona como problema, cuando compilas o usas el play deberias ver cual mensaje genera. Ademas como te comentan no subas una foto, sube un print screen de la pantalla

Comment: No veo el namespace en tu codigo

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez tienes razón buena vista. Aunque eso no debería hacer que le salieran esos errores. Tambien es extraño que le falten ciertos using que en la plantilla por defecto aparecen. Es posible que esto sea un código copiado tal cual de algun sitio?

Comment: Si, trata de poner comentarios en una linea con el boton de visual studio o con `ctrl + k + ctrl + u`. Es extraño que reconozca las palabras claves dentro del comentario.

Comment: mostrar la lista de errores al compilar en VS

Comment: @Pikoh perdón por tardar tanto en contestar no sabia como contestar en particular. Es programa ya lo tenía hecho y el día que me fallo lo copie así como se ve en la imagen y lo pase a un blog de notas, borre ese programa, luego abrí otro nuevo lo pegue y no me iba e hice lo que me dijeron, borre el visual y lo volví a  instalar, pegue lo que tenia copiado y me funciono hasta que cerré el programa y cuando lo volví a abrir me dio el mismo fallo, entonces hice el programa sin copiarlo desde cero y lo he cerrado varías veces y funciona. ¿Si necesito copiar un código largo de algún sitio no puedo?

Comment: Claro que deberías poder copiar. Pero mira la respuesta de @lucianoMontañez por si tuviera algo que ver

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez
He probado `ctrl + k +ctrl + u` que supongo que sera probar con las dos configuraciones una con **k** y otra con **u** y no me salia nada y con el botón de visual studio no se a que te refieres podrías decirme donde se sitúa y como se acede a el.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes el proyecto configurado con VB .NET, este error esta pidiendo sintaxis de VB NET (`End Namespace`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberias crear un proyecto en c#

New Project -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Web

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page